# Python add an id for specific values

Tags: python, dataframe

how do I add a column for id in dataframe? The values between 0 to 100 should have an id of 1 otherwise 2.

```
  time                    values
 2018-03-19 14:31:17.200  1095
 2018-03-19 14:31:17.300  2296  
 2018-03-19 14:31:17.400  2147   
 2018-03-19 14:31:17.500   309   
 2018-03-19 14:31:17.600   244 
 2018-03-19 14:31:17.700   263  
 2018-03-19 14:31:17.800   548
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with condition created by [`between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html) (default `inclusive=True`):

```
df['id'] = np.where(df['values'].between(0,100), 1,2)
print (df)
                      time  values  id
1  2018-03-19 14:31:17.200    1095   2
2  2018-03-19 14:31:17.300    2296   2
3  2018-03-19 14:31:17.400    2147   2
4  2018-03-19 14:31:17.500     309   2
5  2018-03-19 14:31:17.600     244   2
6  2018-03-19 14:31:17.700     263   2
7  2018-03-19 14:31:17.800     548   2
```

Comment: @SungchanKim - You are welcome! Small advice -You can also add to question what you try, your code, also some error if happens for avoid downvotes.